# Why is the following bash script not working when called with nohup?

Tags: bash, shell, nohup

A script like the following:

```
#!/bin/bash

function hello {

        echo "Hello World"

}

hello
```

will work fine but when I call it with [nohup](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nohup)

```
nohup ./myScript.sh
```

the script no longer works and the following is printed:

```
./myScript.sh: 5: ./myScript.sh: function: not found
Hello World
./myScript.sh: 9: ./myScript.sh: Syntax error: "}" unexpected
```

I know that there is no point in using `nohup` for this script since it runs fairly quick but I have another script that is going to take several hours to run and I have used that function syntax in it. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Worked here; what system are you on?

Comment: Those line numbers don't correspond to that script; is that the exact script that you are running?

Comment: @BrianCampbell Sorry for that, there were some empty lines that I deleted after I ran the script. The text of script is the same though.

Comment: Try instead of `function hello {` the simple `hello() {` - the `function` is bash-ism. maybe your /bin/bash isn't bash.. ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Note that to [declare a function in POSIX standard shell](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/utilities/xcu_chap02.html#tag_02_09_05), you just write the function name followed by a pair of empty parentheses, and a body in curly brackets:

```
#!/bin/bash

hello() {
    echo "Hello World"
}

hello
```

Some shells, like bash, also accept the `function` keyword to declare functions, but based on your error message, it looks like the shell that you are using does not accept it. For portability, it would be best to use the POSIX standard declaration style.

The reason you see the difference between running the script directly and running the script under `nohup` is the blank lines at the beginning of the file. The **`#!` need to be the first two characters of the file** in order to specify the interpreter, otherwise that is just a comment. It looks like when executed from within a Bash shell, the script gets interpreted by Bash and it recognizes the Bash extension. But when run from `nohup`, it gets interpreted by `sh`, which on some systems is a more bare-bones shell like `dash` that only supports the POSIX syntax above.

Comment: +1; good guess re error message: it's exactly what you get when you run that script with `dash` (contradicting the shebang line in the question). However, I wouldn't worry so much about _portability_ as I'd worry about ensuring that it is indeed _bash_ executing the script.

Comment: @mklement0 Expanded my answer based on his comment above that he had blank lines at the start of the script. That would explain why it was not being executed by bash; the [shebang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shebang_%28Unix%29) needs to be the first two characters in the file.

Comment: A quick test tells me: `bash` and `ksh` run executable script files without a [valid] shebang line - when invoked stand-alone - _themselves_, whereas `zsh` and `dash` default to `sh` (as does `nohup`) - I'm unclear on how exactly `bash` and `ksh` do that.

Comment: The mistake was, indeed, the fact that the shebang was not the first two characters of the file. The script works fine now when ran with nohup.

Comment: @mklement0 Bash interprets scripts without a `#!` itself because it calls [`execve`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/execve.2.html), and checks if it failed because of a missing `#!`, executing it itself if so ([source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/bash.git/tree/execute_cmd.c?id=35751626#n5183)). nohup, on the other hand, calls [`execvp`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/execvp.3.html), which has the behavior of defaulting back to interpreting a script with `/bin/sh` ([source](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/gitweb/?p=coreutils.git;a=blob;f=src/nohup.c;h=eca1f51249;hb=HEAD#l220)).